# Cannot connect to localhost error:500

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am currently using mamp in my mac. I have created a file names un.php which has a simple form validation. I want to insert the login/ register information into my table in the local database. 
[image: This is my source code]

I think there might be some error in the form *action* keyword. I tried un.php in the form action, I also tried adding the url of the localhost in it, but the same error 500 is showing up.
Thank You
[image: My output screen in the browser]

Comment: How can be the mysql table field name is "E-Mail"?

Comment: Open error log and read errors.

Comment: post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: @u_mulder how do I open error_log?

Answer (score 0):

You made many mistakes in your code.
the image describe where there were error.
this image show them off.
[image: Your errors]

errors.
1. the firs if parentheses was not closed.
2. when using mysqli_select_db($a, $b), $a is the 'connection name' and $b is the 'database name'
3. on your $c, many errors were made. these remaks must correct them:
you should not use the minus (-) sign. this is about E-mail. the dash will be considered as a minus sign and will return error.
$_POST[name] is not correct. the correct way is $_POST["name"]. the problem with $_POST["name"] will also cause problem because there was many ("). the best way is to define it in a variable and using it. example: $name = $_POST["name"]. 
4. the mysqli_query($a, $b) is writen the same as mysqli_select_db($a, $b).
in mysqli_query($a, $b), $a is the connection name, and $b is the query.
5. if(isset($_POST["submit"])), for me it means nothing because 'submit' is a button but not a field. (i am not sure,  but i tried and it does not work).

I written the important part of the code only.

I have rewritten the code for you. it works fine with me. it s

```html
<html>
<head>
   
</head>
<body>

<h2> PHP Form validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" >
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br/>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email"/>
    <br/>
    Website: <input type="text" name="website" />
    <br/>
    Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows ="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $name = $_POST["name"]; $Email = $_POST["Email"]; $_POST["website"]; $_POST["comment"];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root"; $password = "password";
    $dbase = "test"; 
    $db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    if(!$db) echo "Not connected";
    else {
        $p = mysqli_select_db($db,$dbase);
        if(!$p) echo "Problem";
        else {
        $c = "INSERT INTO Users(name, Email, website, comment) VALUES ('$name', '$Email', '$website', '$comment')";
        if(mysqli_query($db, $c));
    
        }
            }
    mysqli_close($db);
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```